# Using Poisson to find probability in a range

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose the counts recorded by a Geiger counter follow a Poisson process with an average of three counts per minute. What is the probability that the first count occurs between 1 and 2 minutes after start-up?

$\lambda=3$ per minute

Am I supposed to calculate $P(X=2)-P(X=1)$? And would $\lambda$ change between those two terms because of the different time intervals? Very confused.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that a homogeneous Poisson process has exponentially distributed interarrival times, so that the probability of the desired event is simply $$\Pr[1 < T_1 \le 2] = (1 - e^{-2\lambda}) - (1 - e^{-\lambda}) = e^{-\lambda} - e^{-2\lambda}.$$

Comment: And would the $\lambda$ be 3 here?

Comment: @DERPYPENGUIN Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

For the first count to occur between 1 and 2 minutes, then *no count* must occur between 0 and 1 minute, and *at least one* must occur between 1 and 2 minutes.

Find $$\mathsf P(N_{(0;1]}=0, N_{(1;2]}\geq 1)$$

Use the independence and identical distribution of Poisson counts in equally-sized disjoint intervals.